# How to drop groups from grouby object based on a list of indexes?

Tags: python, pandas, drop

After doing groupby for a MultiIndex dataframe, how can I drop groups based on their indexes? The selected indexes are stored in a list called 'idx'.

```
display(idx)
[(2, 2, 29.0),
 (7, 2, 46.0),
 (16, 2, 38.0),
 (16, 2, 47.0),
 (20, 1, 14.0),
 (42, 2, 8.0)]
```

I have tried:

```
#Remove groups 
for i in sorted(idx, reverse=True):
    for j, data in gb:
        if i==j:
            del(gb[i])
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object does not support item deletion
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: `df.drop(idx)` doesn't work?